# How to set author, title and date in KOMA script header (scrlayer-scrpage)?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage

How can I customize the header to have `\author`, the `\title` and the  `\date` in the header and underline it?

Since I use a Koma Script document class I want to avoid the `fancyhdr` package and use `scrlayer-scrpage`. I have tried `\chead{\title \author \date}` but it does not change maybe due to the automark option in `\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}`. I want the header to be on every page except the title page and list of contents.

So in `fancyhdr` the code would be:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Lady Gaga: Test}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\today}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the manual? (https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)  pp. 260 explain this is in quite some detail.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you could 'translate' your `fancyhdr` into `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\ohead{Lady Gaga: Test}
\ihead{\today}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

% If you want to change the font/shape etc.:
%   \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{...}
%   \setkomafont{pagenumber}{...}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you want to automate the `author`/`title` insertion, you could add

```
   ...
\usepackage{titling}
\author{Lady Gaga}
\title{Test}
\date{\today}

\ohead{\theauthor: \thetitle}
\ihead{\thedate}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
   ...
```

[image]